# Is it possible to develop Live Tiles in HTML5 Windows 8 Metro apps?

Tags: c#, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to develop Live Tiles in HTML5 Windows 8 Metro apps or do we need to develop in C# and XAML for that ?

Comment: Check out [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) from MS. See the download marked "C#, JavaScript", is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An app written in any language manages tile updates using WinRT APIs, so there is no difference in capabilities from that perspective. A tile update that creates a live tile is simple a piece of XML that you send to the TileUpdater.Update method, and samples like the [App tiles and badges sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148), the [Secondary tiles sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178), and the [Push and Periodic Notifications sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603) all show you variations on the theme.

On the server side--to create a periodic notification service or one that can issue push notifications--you can pretty much use any server-side language you want like PHP, ASP.NET, etc., because it's just a matter of generating the XML payload for the tiles.

Chapter 13 of my newly-released ebook, *[Programming Windows 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/10/29/free-ebook-programming-windows-8-apps-with-html-css-and-javascript.aspx)*. The ebook is free, so there's no excuse to not download it :)

.Kraig